# Can add my own custom snippets to Big Commerce

Tags: variables, bigcommerce

I have tried to upload my own snippet that replaces the create new account text that is held in the %%LNG_NewCustomerIntro2%% variable. Of course I am thinking this would be as simple as 123 but I guess not.

Does a snippet have to be registered? Or should I just comment out the current code in the snippet I need (or hide it with css) and then add in my code?

It seems this is common with bigcommerce....

Any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can not introduce custom snippets to BigCommerce. Snippets refer to a function in the core application to supply data (thus requiring core code). It is better to remove the existing snippet and provide your own code within the panel or layout file.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Alyss